# Stored Procedure while using variable return value becoming zero

Tags: sql, asp.net

Please check the stored procedure - what is my mistake? I am trying to assign the calculated value to variable.

```
Alter Proc [dbo].[FindAnnualLeave1]
   @Empid varchar(20)
as
   Declare @AnnualPending int

   Select 
      @AnnualPending = (select (0.0821917808219178) * DATEDIFF(d, e.doj,GETDATE())- l.Leaves 
                        where l.EmpLeaveCode = 'Annual')

   From 
      EmployeeLeaves l
   inner join 
      EmployeeMaster e on l.EmpID = e.EmpID
   where 
      l.EmpID = e.EmpID

   return @AnnualPending
Go
```

Nothing is returned by this query. I want to show this variable to asp.net label once the command button clicks. If I am not using variable I mean only select statement its returns the value. I tried both asp and sql.

Comment: Well, for one - your subquery doesn't have a `FROM (tablename)` clause..... also: your `WHERE` clause is not needed at all, since you're **already** defining this link in the `JOIN` condition (where it belongs)

Answer (score 1):

The return type from stored procedure is used to return exit code, which is int

Your computation is resulting in value between 0 and 1

You need to define output variable of type float or numeric(10,4) and return that value

```
 Alter Proc [dbo].[FindAnnualLeave1]
@Empid varchar(20),        
@AnnualPending numeric(10,4) OUTPUT
```

Comment: I change the variable to numeric still return 0.

Comment: you can't return a decimal, you need to define output parameter. Alter Proc [dbo].[FindAnnualLeave1]
Empid varchar(20), @AnnualPending numeric(10,4) OUTPUT

Comment: @NAJEEB, you need to get this value instead of return type

Comment: I need the answer 5.xxxx , I calculated manually with this user. and without stored procedure , it is working fine but with the stored procedure no chance.